# How to get system time format (24 or 12 AM/PM) in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I detect the current time format that is set on user's phone (12 AM/PM or 24 hrs)?

There is a native method in Android:

```
DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context);
```

but, I can't find similar in Flutter.

Answer (score 22):

```
bool is24HoursFormat = MediaQuery.of(context).alwaysUse24HourFormat;
```

Doc [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData/alwaysUse24HourFormat.html) says:

> Whether to use 24-hour format when formatting time.
>
> The behavior of this flag is different across platforms:
>
> On Android this flag is reported directly from the user settings
> called "Use 24-hour format". It applies to any locale used by the
> application, whether it is the system-wide locale, or the custom
> locale set by the application.
>
> On iOS this flag is set to true when
> the user setting called "24-Hour Time" is set or the system-wide
> locale's default uses 24-hour formatting.